# Как изменить цену товара при выборке из БД

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Подскажите пожалуйста, а то вообще не понятно в какую сторону двигаться (так как джун в Битриксе Фреймворке).
Задача стоит следующая:
Необходимо реализовать, чтобы исходная цена товара умножалась на коэффициент из диапазона цен.
*Например диапазон от 100руб до 300руб, то коэффициент равен 1.5 и если цена товара входит в данный диапазон, то в таком случае умножается на этот коэффициент*.

После разбора и прочтения документации и просмотром значения массива $arResult понял, что если находимся на странице карточки товара, то цена товара лежит по следующему пути `$arResult['OFFERS'][0]['CATALOG_PRICE_1']`, но к сожалению не разобрался, где идет выборка дабы внеси свои правки.

Буду благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

Правки лучше вносить в файле result_modifier.php в папке шаблона компонента (изменения, внесенные в массив $arResult попадут в файл шаблона).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо, думаю данный вариант мне не поможет к сожалению, ибо например в других модулях/компонентах также полагаю надо будет менять, что не особо удобно.
На данный момент нашел одно решение, которое работает через крон или агенты (устанавливает соответствующие прайсы от поставщиков).

Comment: Если Вы заливаете в каталог прайсы от поставщиков, то правильнее будет корректировать их в момент заливки. Как вариант, можно подгружать их в закупочную цену, а на событие добавления / апдейта элемента повесить обработчик, который будет рассчитывать розничную цену и записывать ее в тот же элемент. В любом случае, думаю, использование периодических обработчиков для решения этой задачи не оправдано, лучше использовать обработчики событий.

Comment: Спасибо, остановился на первом варианте он правильнее оказался для мое задачи)